# Robots Disallowed workaround

Tags: web-scraping, robots.txt

I'm trying to create a **scraper** , but when I run the following code, it says robots disallowed. This is for my internal purposes, but is there a workaround for Robots Disallowed?

I'm testing it on this website: http://80apptester.80legs.com/ and it's not going through.

```
// This is sample code for building a web scraper.
//
// For this sample, we use
// http://www.houzz.com/pro/jeff-halper/exterior-worlds-landscaping-and-design
// as a sample listing we want to scrape.
// 
// For the full crawler, we will assume the crawl
// starts from http://www.houzz.com/professionals/

var EightyApp = function() {
  this.processDocument = function(html, url, headers, status, jQuery) {

    // We only want to collect data from listing pages
    if (url.match("/pro/") {

      // First we construct an HTML object so we can use Jquery
      var app = this;
      $ = jQuery;
      var $html = app.parseHtml(html, $);
      var object = {};
    
      // Then we use JQuery to find all the attributes we want
      object.name = $html.find('h1').text();
      object.address = $html.find('span[itemprop="streetAddress"]').text();
      object.city = $html.find('span[itemprop="addressLocality"]').text();
      object.state = $html.find('span[itemprop="addressRegion"]').text();
      object.postalcode = $html.find('span[itemprop="postalCode"]').text();
      object.contact = $html.find('dt:contains("Contact:")').next().text();

      // Finally, we return the object as a string
      return JSON.stringify(object);
    }
  }

  this.parseLinks = function(html, url, headers, status, jQuery) {

    // We construct the HTML object for Jquery again
    var app = this;
    var $ = jQuery;
    var $html = app.parseHtml(html, $);
    var links = [];

    // We add all the pages in the directory
    $html.find('a.pageNumber').each(function(i, obj) {
      var link = app.makeLink(url, $(this).attr('href'));
      if (link != null) {
        links.push(link);
      }
    });

    // We add all the listings in the directory
    $html.find('a.pro-title').each(function(i, obj) {
      var link = app.makeLink(url, $(this).attr('href'));
      if (link != null) {
        links.push(link);
      }
    });

    return links;
  }
}

try {
  module.exports = function(EightyAppBase) {
    EightyApp.prototype = new EightyAppBase();
    return new EightyApp();
  }
} catch(e) {
  console.log("Eighty app exists.");
  EightyApp.prototype = new EightyAppBase();
}
```

Comment: Change the user agent?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. Even if you change the agent name, there are other techniques, such a IP filtering, to detect unwanted scrappers.